# Python - NoneType object not callable when chaining getter and setter

Tags: python

I'm trying to use @property and @propertyName.setter to get / set values on different properties but face the following issue when i chain multiple accessors.

This is a simple example i could reproduce my issue:

```
class Toto:

    def __init__(self):

        self._name = None
        self._label = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value


class Tata:

    def __init__(self):

        self._toto = Toto()

    @property
    def toto(self):
        return self._toto

    @toto.setter
    def toto(self, value):
        self._toto = value
```

When i execute this:

```
tata = Tata()
print("Toto name is", tata.toto.name)
tata.toto.name("titi")
print("Toto name is", tata.toto.name)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Toto name is None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radjanidar/projects/music/demo/src/main/script/chainedproperties.py", line 43, in <module>
    tata.toto.name("titi")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why can't i use the setter method on object Toto ?

Comment: I think you should use an assignment, rather than a call when using the setter. I.e. tats.toto.name = “titi”

Comment: Oh, you're perfectly right... i'm coming from Java world and definitly have to change my habits, how I could miss that... many thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined name as a property which changes how you interact with it.

Instead of `tata.toto.name("titi")`, you use `tata.toto.name = "titi"`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use properties. Basically, properties are ways to make function calls act like attributes. When getting and setting them, the decorated getters and setters respectively are called, instead of performing naive attribute lookup.

Accordingly, you want `tata.toto.name = 'titi'`.